# Why won't hot water come out after turning the water main back on?

Tags: plumbing, hot-water, troubleshooting

If someone turns their water main off to work on a plumbing and toilet problem, why would the cold water come on but no hot water. It doesn't come out at all or it will drip.

Why would this be, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please tell us how the water was turned off, ( by water main do you mean the valve that is the first valve on the pip, inside your home,  coming from the the city supply line or the city water valve which in the ground out by the street before it enters your home)? what work specifically was done and how was the water turned back on. Who turned it off and did they do the work and turn it back on. and clarify that when you turn on the hot water side of the faucet that no water comes out or water come out but does not get hot.

Comment: Thank you! the water was turned  off inside the house for the toilet to get fixed on the second floor the pluming between the first and second levels of the house ( stink pipe) while this was being done i didnt realize the washer was running but i do not believe it emptied the tank but the main was turned back on and the cold runs fine the hot doesnt come out at all no cold on hot side just nothing

Comment: I am with Ed on this could be a blockage. have you tried all of the hot water faucets in the house or just one. If it is all affected then the blockage it at or near the water heater. If it one faucet then the blockage is in the faucet or the hot water valve to the faucet.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have no water coming out or just a drip a large chunk of rust or scale could have broken loose from your main and plugged the water heater. I would close and open the valve to the water heater to see if this crumbles or breaks up the debris. If that works it really is time to flush the water heater from the bottom drain. A hose connected to the bottom drain and taken outside or to a close sink or toilet makes this job clean and easy. If you have valves on both the inlet and outlet cycle both. If this works on the outlet side be prepared to clean the faucet aerators. If you get water running and hot water again it is also time to check the Anode rod. Anodes reduce corrosion inside the water heater and are eaten away (Another source of gunk in the bottom of the tank). Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be aware of without knowing the age and condition of water heater it's hard to say. What most people don't know is that every year you should drain your hot water tank. This removes all the rust, silt and sediment that settles in the bottom of the tank. If you're like most of us, and you don't do that yearly then you almost always shortening the life of water heater. If you have ever seen a water heater cut in half after just 5 years of use you would most likely not want to drink anything coming out of that water heater. Just google it ...

My recommendations is to check the pilot light first if gas water heater or electrical panel for electric water heater to see if it something very simple to fix. If not call a licensed HVAC/plumber to help you out.

Please also drain it. That is what the large spigot coming off bottom side of it is used for. Just hook up your garden hose up to it and turn it on. You might be surprised of what comes out the other end once it gets to the bottom. If clean when completely emptied then your done.If not let it feel up again and empty.

Comment: Dude, she said the hot water  "doesn't come out at all", not that it doesn't get hot.

Answer (score 0):

Because the hot water valve on your tank has been shut off so you wouldn’t burn up your units or you're airlocked.

So open the pressure valve to reduce air, then start to refill, then close.

Comment: pls use hol wrds, ltrs r chep